# Jenkins Pipeline Groovy Script: Use `mail` in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to send an email when a **Pipeline** build on Jenkins fails. An example can be found here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/jenkinsfile-examples/nodejs-build-test-deploy-docker-notify/Jenkinsfile

My concrete **groovy** script looks as follows:

```
#!groovy
node('') {
   def env = ["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'jdk1.8.0_131'}", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'maven_3.1.1'}/bin:${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin", "PATH+GRADLE=${tool 'gradle_4.1'}/bin:${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin" ]

   def err = null
   currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

  try {
   stage('errorStage') {
        dir('error') {
            git url: "unknown", branch: "master"
            withEnv(env) {
                sh "mvn -Pjenkins-build clean deploy"
            }
        }
    }
  } catch (caughtError) {
      println "caught error :" + caughtError
      err = caughtError
      currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
      mail (body:
            "Pipeline error: ${err}\nFix me.",
            from: 'jenkins@x.com',
            subject: 'Pipeline build failed',
            to: 'recipient@x.com')
  } finally {
      /* Must re-throw exception to propagate error */
      if (err) {
          throw err
      }
  }

}
```

Actually, nothing ever happens, although the exception is being caught correctly and the build fails. Is there anything required to be able to use `mail`?! Maybe another Jenkins plugin or something?

Comment: Did you configure address of your smtp server in Jenkins? If yes, then you should check if address is reachable from machine using groovy shell.

Comment: it's configured correctly in the 'Email Notifications' section and also in 'Extended E-mail Notification', which I installed additionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself by using `emailext` plugin on Jenkins instead of `mail`. The code looks as follows now:

```
emailext body: "Pipeline error: ${err}\nPlease go to ${BUILD_URL} and verify the build",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
                subject: "'${JOB_NAME}' (${BUILD_NUMBER}) failed",
                to: '...'
```