# Send a automated email from jenkins for passed build in every hour exclude failed on

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

How to integrate the bitbucket repository to Jenkins and get it executed every 5 mins. get an email notification for every failed builds upfront and get a notification of all passed build every hour.
Use Case

1. Create an automation test for a few page URLs - Done
2. Execute it     every 5 mins (Schedule with Jenkins) - Done
3. Send an email as soon as any build got fail  - Done
4. **Send an email every 1 hour for all passed build in last one hours (exclude the fail one)** - Need help on this

Comment: Too much questions in one question. Please update your question to avoid down-votes. Did you research something? Show us your effort.

Comment: Thanks !! Use Case wheere I need help - Send an email every 1 hour for all passed build in last one hours (exclude the fail one) - Need help on this

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine:

- Build periodically trigger

  - https://blogs.perficient.com/2022/08/23/configuring-jenkins-jobs-by-using-cron/
  - https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/how-to-schedule-a-jenkins-job
  - [How do I schedule jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-do-i-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)
- Groovy code to query all success builds of last hour

  - [How to get only Successful builds from last 24hrs using groovy script in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921439/how-to-get-only-successful-builds-from-last-24hrs-using-groovy-script-in-jenkins)
  - [How to get only Successful builds from last 24hrs using groovy script in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921439/how-to-get-only-successful-builds-from-last-24hrs-using-groovy-script-in-jenkins)
  - Due to the complexity and existent plugins, this should be a scripted pipeline without sandbox and it should be approved by the jenkins admin
- Email Extension Plugin

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216879/3957754
  - https://automationreinvented.blogspot.com/2021/06/how-to-send-email-notification-in.html
  - https://naiveskill.com/jenkins-pipeline-email-notification/

### Every hour trigger

[image]

### Query builds with groovy + mail

```
import hudson.model.*

node {
    def nowDateInMilliseconds = new Date().getTime();
    def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('my_job-full_name');
    def lastHourSucessBuild = [];
    
    for(def build in job.builds){
        if (build.result!=hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS) continue;
        
        def lastSuccessBuildDateOnMillis = build.getTime().getTime();
        long diff = nowDateInMilliseconds - lastSuccessBuildDateOnMillis;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);         
        println build.number+" : Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes
        if(diffMinutes<60)lastHourSucessBuild.add(build.number)
    }
    
    println "Last hour success builds: " + lastHourSucessBuild
    
    emailext (
      subject: "Last hour success builds",
      body: "Last hour success builds: " + lastHourSucessBuild,
      to: "test@gmail.com"
    )
}
```

Full job config [here](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/2c3b7a5903de0ad77f52da1cb3176ba3)

### Advices

I advice to try bit by bit:

- config the emailext and send a mail as demo
- config the build trigger and print a message every minute

Only if you achieve these demos, combine all in one scripted pipeline ;)